# Flatten array-valued properties up into their single element value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, underscore.js

In my Node.js app, I have some ugly data:

```
{"rn":["801"],"destSt":["30089"],"destNm":["95th/Dan Ryan"],"trDr":["5"],"nextStaId":["41430"],"nextStpId":["30276"],"nextStaNm":["87th"],"prdt":["20151003 12:36:48"],"arrT":["20151003 12:38:48"],"isApp":["0"],"isDly":["0"],"flags":[""],"lat":["41.75042"],"lon":["-87.62518"],"heading":["179"]}
```

As you can see, each object property inexplicably contains an array with the value that should be directly the value of that propety.

I'd like to move everything up one level so that it looks like:

```
{"rn":"801","destSt":"30089","destNm":"95th/Dan Ryan"}
```

(etc)

In no case will any of those arrays contain any more than one value.

What's the best way to do this? I've tried underscore's flatten to no avail.

And I'm not sure how to go about Googling this. :)

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2z24p8p0/ **Steps:** **1** Iterate over object **2.** Check if the value is array and has length 1 **3.** If yes, Replace the array by its element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misled about the sophistication of the data (I assumed I could just for-each into each one and pick things out.)

Really my data is set of routes which contains an set of trains which contain properties. The data I posted was just the data from train one one route.

So I did this:

```
        _.each(routes,function(route, rt_index, list) {
            _.each(route, function (train, train_index,list){
                _.each(train, function (property, property_index,list){
                    routes[rt_index][train_index][property_index] = property[0];
                });
            });
        });
```

Though I'm sure there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the JSON reviver function to modify the values. The benefit of doing it this way is that it iterates through nested objects too.

```
JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value = value[0];
  }
  return value;
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/hexogaqeja/edit?js,console**

Comment: Sure, I love the reviver as much as anyone, but in this case the OP explicitly stated that the arrays occurred only at the first level, and although it seems the values are always strings, this approach won't work for arrays containing functions, regexps etc., in case they are there. Also, although I'm not generally one to worry about micro-optimization, this is going to be quit slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = {"rn":["801"],"destSt":["30089"],"destNm":["95th/Dan Ryan"],"trDr":["5"],"nextStaId":["41430"],"nextStpId":["30276"],"nextStaNm":["87th"],"prdt":["20151003 12:36:48"],"arrT":["20151003 12:38:48"],"isApp":["0"],"isDly":["0"],"flags":[""],"lat":["41.75042"],"lon":["-87.62518"],"heading":["179"]},

newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(result, item){
  result[item] = obj[item][0];  

  return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: Using `reduce` is a rather weird way to map one object to another.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the keys and change their values:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] = obj[key][0])
```

This modifies the object in place. If you would prefer to create another object

```
function unarrayize(obj) {
  var result = {};
  for (var k in obj) result[k] = obj[k][0];
  return result;
}
```

If you want to use Underscore:

```
_.mapObject(obj, function(val) { return val[0]; })
```

Comment: Did you mean `Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] = obj[key][0])`?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it with the Query String core module:

```
var qs = require('querystring');

var obj = {"rn":["801"],"destSt":["30089"],"destNm":["95th/Dan Ryan"],"trDr":["5"],"nextStaId":["41430"],"nextStpId":["30276"],"nextStaNm":["87th"],"prdt":["20151003 12:36:48"],"arrT":["20151003 12:38:48"],"isApp":["0"],"isDly":["0"],"flags":[""],"lat":["41.75042"],"lon":["-87.62518"],"heading":["179"]};

var newObj = qs.parse(qs.stringify(obj));
```

May not be the best way, but it does what you need.

Comment: Hmm darn, it worked for me though?

BEFORE:
{ rn: [ '801' ],

  destSt: [ '30089' ],

  destNm: [ '95th/Dan Ryan' ],

  trDr: [ '5' ],

  nextStaId: [ '41430' ],

(and so on)...

AFTER:
{ rn: '801',

  destSt: '30089',

  destNm: '95th/Dan Ryan',

  trDr: '5',

  nextStaId: '41430',

(and so on)...